# Before Insert Trigger not working as defined

Tags: mysql

I am writing mysql before insert trigger but its not working. Mysql is giving no errors but column value is not updated.

```
BEGIN
set NEW.message_state = CASE
WHEN New.user_id = '11' THEN 'Visible'
ELSE New.message_state
END
```

Comment: You must use two `END` - one closes CASE and another closes BEGIN.

Answer (score 1):

Your example gives an syntax error.

Example solution with case

```
BEGIN
    CASE WHEN NEW.user_id = '11' THEN 
      SET NEW.message_state = 'Visible';
    ELSE   
      BEGIN 
      END;      
    END CASE;  
END
```

`ELSE` statement is needed, because in case of user_id <> 11 MYSQL will try to find next WHEN or ELSE clausule, and will throw error if there is none.

Example solution with second CASE

```
BEGIN
    SET NEW.message_state = (select 
           CASE WHEN NEW.user_id = '11' THEN 'Visible' 
                ELSE NEW.message_state 
           END);  
END
```

But this syntax is quite overcomplitaced for what you try to achieve. Simple IF will be enough

```
BEGIN
    IF NEW.user_id = '11' THEN
       SET NEW.message_state = 'Invisible';
    END IF; 
END;
```

[DB Fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=986770248380896885862bba4086e9d8)

Comment: ELSE  option in 1st code is excess and can be removed completely.

Comment: @Akina so play with DB Fiddle and check what will happen. Error will be thrown `Case not found for CASE statement` if user_id <> 11.

Comment: Maybe there is a solution to get rid of this BEGIN END ... but i didn't find a way

Comment: Oops... I missed that you use CASE statement and not operator (like in OP). Sorry.

Comment: Good point, I've added second syntax for case as operator. Didn't find a way to use it without select clausule